# Крутить div с помощью события mousedrag

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем хай! Есть вот такая "типа" ручка эквалайзера:

```css
.knob {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.knob::after {
  content: "";
  width: 2px;
  height: 48%;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 50%;
  margin-top: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="knob">
</div>
```

Помогите на JS сделать следующее:

При событии `onMouseDrag` надо изменять угол поворота `div.knob` но при этом угол не должен превышать 170º и -170º, то есть чтобы не было значений больше 170º и больше -170º.

Пример вот:

[image: пример]

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Symphony/pfs12rye/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В упрощённом виде это делается так:

```js
var knob = document.querySelector('.knob'),
  isMouseDown = false,
  mouseDownPositionX;

//выбор центра вращения:
knob.style.transform = 'translate(35,35)';

document.onmousedown = function(e) {
  if (e.target == knob) {
    mouseDownPositionX = e.pageX;
    isMouseDown = true
  }
};

document.onmouseup = function() {
  isMouseDown = false
};

document.onmousemove = function(e) {
  if (isMouseDown) {
    var distanceX = e.pageX - mouseDownPositionX;

    if (distanceX > 170)
      distanceX = 170;

    if (distanceX < -170)
      distanceX = -170;

    knob.style.transform = 'rotate(' + distanceX + 'deg)';
  }
};
```

```css
.knob {
  margin-left: 300px;
  /*только для примера. Это надо удалить*/
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.knob::after {
  content: "";
  width: 2px;
  height: 48%;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 50%;
  margin-top: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="knob"></div>
```

Вам ещё понадобится:

1. [Правильное положение мышки](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7790764/)
2. [Справочник CSS-rotate](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate)

Comment: Спасибо, а что еще следует дописать чтоб под сенсор работало?

Comment: @EugenEray, [Touch-события. Справочник](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Touch_events). Нужны ещё touchstart, touchend, touchmove.